Fill NA in pandas column with new UUID
My dataframe includes a column with UUID's. Some values may be missing, and I need to fill them with a new UUID.
Of course, if I do:
df["B"].fillna(str(uuid.uuid4()))

all missing entries will be filled with the same value, which is not what I want. I would instead the uuid4() function to be executed every time.
How can I achieve this result?

Use a mask with isna and a short list comprehension with boolean indexing:
m = df['B'].isna()

df.loc[m, 'B'] = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in range(m.sum())]

Example output:
                                      B
0                                   1.0
1  26c1bdaf-3975-45d3-8c9e-f5a67c712b56
2  44821c0d-aee6-4e19-bd8c-c92df6ec81d5
3                                   2.0
4  a9103c12-7af4-4d23-b9a6-86ddfced3d17

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, None, None, 2, None]})


you  can use apply method without defining a separate function
it will check if the value of x is not missing by using (pd.notna(x)).
If it is not missing, it remain as it is.
If it is missing, it generates a new UUID and converts it to a string using str(uuid.uuid4())
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.notna(x) else str(uuid.uuid4()))

by using the input :
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [None, 'existing_uuid', None, None]}

the output will be :
0  1  4bfd0d53-2a0e-4b3a-92af-8e284c754622
1  2                         existing_uuid
2  3  c1506871-6b98-431f-ac05-f06f24b58641
3  4  7feab279-5a14-449d-b402-d266c1335a21

